# It has never worked when I try to do "buyToken" test on a deployed Token_CrowdsaleDeployer contract. It asks "beneficienry". what is this beneficiary?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, ico

The following is the programme.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvj2t.png)

I tried to "buyToken" after the deployment. I put a wallet address in beneficiery where I wanted the purchased token to be stored. Then it came up with an error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and post the code as text (you can use markdown 3 backticks syntax or the `{}` button in the editor) - that enables answerers to copy-paste parts of your code and troubleshoot more easily.

Comment: @PetrHejda, check the following.                                                                        pragma solidity ^0.5.15;

import "./KaseiCoin.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";

Comment: contract KaseiCoinCrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale { 
    constructor(
        uint256 rate,
        address payable wallet,
        KaseiCoin token
    ) public Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token) {
        // constructor can stay empty
    }
}

Comment: contract KaseiCoinCrowdsaleDeployer {
    address public kasei_token_address;
    address public kasei_crowdsale_address;

    // Add the constructor.
    constructor(
       string memory name,
       string memory symbol,
       address payable wallet

Comment: My crowdsale contract address: 0xddaAd340b0f1Ef65169Ae5E41A8b10776a75482d

Comment: @PetrHejda, the crowdsale address: 0xddaAd340b0f1Ef65169Ae5E41A8b10776a75482d

Comment: @petrHejda. what is the wallet? where can I find the token address? I deloyed a token contract first before deploying this crowdsale contract. Is the token address the token contract address? it doesn't work. When I call BuyToken, it just failed. the rate is 1. i tried 1ether or 1wei, both failed.

Comment: Please use the `Edit` button at the bottom of the question and post the code as part of the question - it's easier to read that way. The code that you shared so far doesn't contain any `buyToken` function.